# Concat stream at the arbitrary position

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

Yet another question about RxJava. Im on fire this week.

I have the following problem to solve with RxJava:

I have a stream of `Model` objects which I transform into stream of `ViewModel` objects. Everything is pretty straight forward - I just use `map` operator and it works fine. However I have one requirement - sometimes I need to add fake `ViewModel` after the element which satisfy given criteria. I.e:

```
models:     ---1----2----3----4----5----6----->
                      vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
viewmodels: --A(1)-A(2)-A(3)-A(4)-A(5)-A(6)--->
```

Now let's say I want to add fake viewmodel after the last odd number in the viewmodels stream:

```
result:     --A(1)-A(2)-A(3)-A(4)-A(5)-A(-1)-A(6)--->
```

I looked at `concatMap` operator - it allows me to extend given stream with more elements, but Im not sure how do I add the logic of adding new elements at the arbitrary position.

**EDIT**: Position for adding fake model is not known. "last odd number" case was chosen just as a example. In real situation I have more complex logic of deciding where fake model goes. There is a chance fake model should not be added at all if item which satisfies given criteria is not found in the stream

**EDIT2**: To get more real, both my `Model` and `ViewModel` classes have boolean flag inside. Let's call this flag `isFinished`. In my case I need to add fake viewmodel after the last "finished" item in the stream. If none of them is finished - no fake viewmodel should be added. So ultimately I have maximum one fake model added

Comment: specific use case please

Answer (score 0):

In your example the decision to insert a fake `ViewModel` depends on knowing when the stream has completed. The last odd number is an easy case to deal with using `buffer` to look ahead a little. When the end of the stream is close the buffer will not be of size 3 and you can check the index to see if you are at an odd position. This should give you the general idea and I leave it to you to think of the edge cases properly:

```
modelsWithIndex
    .buffer(3,1)
    .concatMap(list -> {
         if (list.size()==3 || list.get(0).index % 2 == 0)
             return Observable.just(list.get(0).model);
         else  
             return Observable.just(list.get(0).model, createFakeModel());
    });
```

After Edit2 it seems that the distance to the end of the stream can be arbitrarily large so `buffer` is not the way to go. For this case I would use `Transfomers.toListWhile()` from [rxjava-extras](http://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava-extras). The condition function to pass as a parameter would return false once `model.finished` returns true then you could use the `.buffer(2,1).flatMap()` trick to detect the last list and return `Observable.just(fakeModel).concatWith(Observable.from(list))` or if not the last just return `Observable.from(list)`.

Comment: Odd number example was just a showcase. In real life I have more complex logic for figuring out where does fake model go. There is a chance fake model shouldn't be added at all if element which satisfies given criteria is not present in the stream

Comment: Each use case may have different solutions. You need to be specific about your use case I think if you want an answer.

Comment: I don't see the completed requirement, but otherwise, concatMap + just is the way to go.

Comment: Updated with how to deal with Edit2